# SaltStack: NamespacedDictWrapper object has no attribute

Tags: saltstack

I get this message, and I have no clue why

```
salt:/srv # salt-ssh foo-archiv state.sls monitoring

[ERROR   ] Rendering exception occurred: Jinja variable 'salt.utils.context.NamespacedDictWrapper object' has no attribute 'monitoring'
[CRITICAL] Rendering SLS 'base:monitoring' failed: Jinja variable 'salt.utils.context.NamespacedDictWrapper object' has no attribute 'monitoring'
foo-archiv:
    - Rendering SLS 'base:monitoring' failed: Jinja variable 'salt.utils.context.NamespacedDictWrapper object' has no attribute 'monitoring'
```

What can be the root of this problem?

The same sls-files works for a different host!

Comment: I had this same problem but it was due to a comment that had a non-existing variable in it. (sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment)

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question.

The file pillar/foo-archiv.sls` exists.

But the host `foo-archiv` was missing in `pillar/top.sls`.

In our setup the file `pillar/foo-archiv.sls` gets included in `pillar/top.sls`.

Comment: in my case I had mis-spelled the minion key name in the pillar/top.sls file